# Unable to link test support library to application under test

Tags: android, automated-tests, adt, robotium

In our Robotium test automation framework, we have multiple test projects sharing common functionality. I decided to create a support library that could be used by all test projects. I need to link both test projects and the test support library to the application under test, since both of them use the resources of the application under test.

Visualization of the situation (arrow means "uses"):

```
    -----> app-under-test <----
   /                           \
  /                             \
test-project -------------> test-support-lib
```

In Eclipse, everything works just fine after I set up the build paths correctly.

However, when I try to build the tests from the command line - command line building is required for Jenkins - building the support library fails with

> -compile:
>   ...
>       [javac] E:\test-support-lib\src\com\test\support\lib\TestSupportUtility.java:21: error: package com.app.under.test.R does not exist
>       [javac]     pSolo.getString(com.app.under.test.R.string.TEST_STRING)

I have linked both test and test support lib in the similar manner:

- `android update test-project --path E:\test-project --main
  E:\app-under-test`
- `android update test-project --path
  E:\test-support-lib --main E:\app-under-test`

How can I use the resources of app-under-test in test-support-lib?